# Проблема подключения к VPN L2TP на MacOS

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-server, windows-server-2012, l2tp

После подключения к VPN L2TP на макбуке отваливается интернет, но на сервер можно заходить и работать. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: в настройке маршрутизации. за помощью обратитесь к администратору вашего l2tp-сервера.

Comment: я бы и хотел узнать как можно сделать маршрутизацию на маке для доступа. Тк клиенты с w10 подключаются нормально, и могут работать не меняя свой родной ip при выключенной галочке в подключении vpn - "Use default gateway on remote network"